Пользовательская кнопка FancyBox не работает в видео
у меня есть кастомная кнопка на FancyBox, но она не отображается в video,
Кнопка есть в изображениях, но нету в видео.
Как мне добавить эту кнопку в видео?
  useEffect(() => {
    Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox="gallery"]', {
      Toolbar: {
        items: {
          search: {
            tpl: '<button class="f-button">Типо кнопка svg</button>',
            click: () => {
              const slide = Fancybox.getSlide();
              scrollToMessage({ chat_id: chat.chat_id, message_id: slide.messageId });
            },
          },
        },
        display: {
          left: ["zoom", "fullscreen"],
          right: ["search", "close"],
        },
      },      
    });
  
    return () => Fancybox.unbind('[data-fancybox="gallery"]');
  }, []);

примерно так выглядит код
Пытался искать ответы на гитхабе, но там подобных проблем нет

Решение :
useEffect(() => {
Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox="gallery"]', {
Toolbar: {
enabled: true,
